# string remove htmls

Tags: c#, html, regex

I would like a regex to remove html tags and &nbsp, &quot etc from a string. The regex I have is to remove the html tags but not the others mentioned. I'm using .Net 4

Thanks

CODE:

```
     String result = Regex.Replace(blogText, @"<[^>]*>", String.Empty);
```

Comment: Before you proceed, take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: Regex and HTML are never a good mix. Have a look @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5496704/strip-html-and-css-in-c

Comment: this could be easily done with HtmlAgilityPack, see [Stripping all html tags with Html Agility Pack](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3140919/102112)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to build on what you what you already created, you can change it to the following:

```
String result = Regex.Replace(blogText, @"<[^>]*>|&\w+", String.Empty);
```

It means...

1. Either match tags as you defined...
2. ...or match a `&` followed by at least one *word character* `\w` -- as many as possible.

Neither of these two work in all nasty cases, but usually it does.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use Regular Expressions, use the HTML Agility pack:

http://www.codeplex.com/htmlagilitypack