# Strip all HTML tags, except anchor tags

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, anchor, strip-tags

I'm importing data from 1 database to another. I've been requested to strip all HTML content, as its messy and not valid, and just keep the links

I currently use the following VB.NET function to strip all HTML tags from a string of content:

```
Public Shared Function StripHTML(ByVal htmlString As String) As String
    Dim pattern As String = "<(.|\n)*?>"
    Return Regex.Replace(htmlString, pattern, String.Empty)
End Function
```

I'm looking for a way of stripping all, but `a` (anchor) tags from the content.

For example if I have the following HTML content:

```
<table>
  <tr>
     <td>
         Lorem <a href="http://google.com">Ipsum</a>
     </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

This will simply become:

```
Lorem <a href="http://google.com">Ipsum</a>
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Can you give us a little bit more information about your task? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm importing data from 1 database to another. I've been requested to strip all HTML content, as its messy and not valid, and just keep the links

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you use [Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)

also check this question/answers: [HTML Agility Pack strip tags NOT IN whitelist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3107514/html-agility-pack-strip-tags-not-in-whitelist)

Comment: Do you have any vb.net examples? I'm struggling to convert this code

Comment: @Curt google and SO SearchBox are your dear friends ;-) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3140919/stripping-all-html-tags-with-html-agility-pack

Answer (score 0):

You could try this

```
<((?!a[ ]).|\n)*?>
```

Comment: This still removes the `</a>`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of stripping all tags but the anchors you can use reverse logic and get only the anchors.
Why don't you try to use the following pattern to extract anchors:

```
(?<anchor><a.*?href=[""'](?<url>.*?)[""'].*?>(?<name>.*?)</a>)
```

HTH
Pavel

Comment: I need the content which is also not an anchor though, not just a list of the anchors